# Getting 404 statuscode in postman for Spring boot API connected with SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My Spring boot project is connected to MSSQL Server but while hitting the post response getting 404 status code in postman:

Postman:

```
  {
    "timestamp": 1625696983693,
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/house"
  }
```

MyController.java

```
public class MyController {
    
    @Autowired
    private HouseService houseService;
    
    // get the values
    @GetMapping("/house")
    public List<House> getApiHouseValues(){
        return this.houseService.getHouseValues();
    }
    
    // add values
    @PostMapping("/house")
    public GateHouse addApiHouseValues(@RequestBody House house) {
        return this.houseService.addHouseValues(house);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
server.port=9090
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://server-name;databaseName=log
spring.datasource.username=loguser
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

# hibernate configuration
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update 
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

Also checked in SQL Server but database is empty, don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: check the console / log

Comment: Do you have the controllers and services in different packages from the main class? If so, try using @ComponentScan(list all packages here) to list different packages so that the they are available in the classpath. Is this a Rest controller that you have there?

Comment: Do you have @RestController annotation on MyController class?

Comment: @SaurabhSingh no I will add RestController annotations and check it in again

Comment: It is solved thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

404 mean page not found add below things on controller level.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value ="/")
public class MyController {

GetMapping("house")
public List<House> getApiHouseValues(){
    return this.houseService.getHouseValues();
 }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I will add it and check it again